# Siddhi App, 'Output Rate Limiting' clause misbehaviour in Joins

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am facing a non-expected behaviour when using the clause `output every` along with table `join` clause.

- I have an basic app, with one `input` stream, and 2 tables, which store a different list of values. Then, there are also 2 queries,
- The first `query1` will join with `table1`, and when there is a match will `output first every 5 sec`.
- Second `query2` will do similarly, will join `table2`, and will output first value found every 5 sec.
- The goal of this is, every 5 seconds, when there is a value in `input` stream which is contained into table 1, there will be a match, and if there is a value contained into table 2, there will be a different match, and both queries will keep silent until next 5 seconds block.

the app is the following

```sql
@App:name("delays_tables_join")

define stream input(value string);
define stream table_input(value string);
define table table1(value string);
define table table2(value string);

@sink(type='log')
define stream LogStream (value string);

-- fill table1
@info(name='insert table 1')
from table_input[value == '1']
insert into table1;

-- fill table2
@info(name='insert table 2')
from table_input[value == '2']
insert into table2;

-- query input join with table 1, output once every 5 sec
@info(name='query1')
from input join table1 on input.value == table1.value
select input.value
output first every 5 sec
insert into LogStream;

-- query input join with table 2, output once every 5 sec
@info(name='query2')
from input join table2 on input.value == table2.value
select input.value
output first every 5 sec
insert into LogStream;
```

- When this app is run,first its sent to `table_input` the values `1`, and `2` to fill both tables
- And then, it starts sending to the input stream repeatedly values: `1`, `2`, `1`, `2`, `1`, `2`...
- It is expected to have in `LogStream` 2 values every 5 seconds, the first appearance of `1` value, and the first appearance of value `2`.
- But instead, just the first occurrence of value `1` appears all the time, but not the value `2`

```
[2020-04-02_18-55-16_498] INFO {io.siddhi.core.stream.output.sink.LogSink} - delays_tables_join : LogStream : Event{timestamp=1585846516098, data=[1], isExpired=false} 
[2020-04-02_18-55-21_508] INFO {io.siddhi.core.stream.output.sink.LogSink} - delays_tables_join : LogStream : Event{timestamp=1585846521098, data=[1], isExpired=false}
```

> Please, note that, when there are no table joins involved, both queries work as expected. Example without joins:

```sql
@App:name("delays")
define stream Input(value string);

@sink(type='log')
define stream LogStream (value string);

@info(name='query1')
from Input[value == '1']
select value
output first every 5 sec
insert into LogStream;

@info(name='query2')
from Input[value == '2']
select value
output first every 5 sec
insert into LogStream;
```

this will produce the following output:

```
[2020-04-02_18-53-50_305] INFO {io.siddhi.core.stream.output.sink.LogSink} - delays : LogStream : Event{timestamp=1585846430304, data=[1], isExpired=false} 
[2020-04-02_18-53-50_706] INFO {io.siddhi.core.stream.output.sink.LogSink} - delays : LogStream : Event{timestamp=1585846430305, data=[2], isExpired=false} 
[2020-04-02_18-53-55_312] INFO {io.siddhi.core.stream.output.sink.LogSink} - delays : LogStream : Event{timestamp=1585846438305, data=[1], isExpired=false} 
[2020-04-02_18-53-56_114] INFO {io.siddhi.core.stream.output.sink.LogSink} - delays : LogStream : Event{timestamp=1585846439305, data=[2], isExpired=false}
```

.

I was wondering if this behaviour is expected, or there is any error at all in the design of the application.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the results as in the "without join" by fixing the "insert table 2" query by changing the **table1** to **table2** in **insert into** line

```
-- fill table2
@info(name='insert table 2')
from table_input[value == '2']
insert into table1;
```

Comment: Hi @Anusha, many thanks for your reply. Yes, you are right, there was a typo in the copied example, i will edit it. Although, once changed, the real example, still seems to not work as expected.
I played this example on siddhi-tooling-5.1.3, and recorded the output.

You can see here what is the current behaviour
https://youtu.be/GEVKefoPnw0